# Solution verification: when is the irreflexive closure of a relation defined?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, relations

I am working on a problem that states the following:

> When is it possible to define the irreflexive closure of a relation $R$, that is, a relation that contains $R$, is irreflexive, and is contained in every irreflexive relation that contains $R$?

**Attempt:**
First note that a relation $R$ defined on a set $A$ is irreflexive if $(a,a) \notin R$ for all $a \in A$.

Suppose $R$ is a relation defined in a set $A$. Let $S$ be an irreflexive relation on $A$ that contains $R$. Then $(a,a)\notin S$ for all $a \in A$ and $R \subseteq S$ which implies that $(a,a) \notin R$ for all $a \in A$. Therefore, $R$ is irreflexive on $A$. Hence, unless $R$ is irreflexive, we can't define irreflexive closure of $R$.

Finally, note that when $R$ is irreflexive, the irreflexive closure of $R$ is $R$ itself.

**Question:** is my approach correct?

Comment: seems sound to me

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is perfectly correct! After all, since the closure $S$ must be irreflexive, then $(a,a) \not \in S$ $\forall a \in A$, but that in turn enforces the same restrictions on subsets of $S$, namely the relation we're trying to close. Thus the closure only exists for relations which themselves are already irreflexive.

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*